# Critical sections - Thinking in Java example

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I read now book Thinking in Java, chapter about critical sections and I cannot understand an example, because I got exceptions which are not described in the book. An example looks like below:

```
class Pair {
    private int x, y;

    public Pair(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Pair() {
        this(0, 0);
    }

    public int getX() { return x; }
    public int getY() { return y; }

    public void incrementX() { x++; }
    public void incrementY() { y++; }

    public class PairValuesNotEqualException extends RuntimeException {
        public PairValuesNotEqualException() {
            super("Values are not equal: " + Pair.this);
        }
    }

    public void checkState() {
        if (x != y) {
            throw new PairValuesNotEqualException();
        }
    }
}

abstract class PairManager {
    AtomicInteger checkCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    protected Pair p = new Pair();

    public synchronized Pair getPair() {
        // Make copies to protect the original
        return new Pair(p.getX(), p.getY());
    }

    public abstract void increment();
}

// synchronization of the whole method
class PairManager1 extends PairManager {

    @Override
    public synchronized void increment() {
        p.incrementX();
        p.incrementY();
    }
}

// Critical section
class PairManager2 extends PairManager {

    @Override
    public void increment() {
        synchronized (this) {
            p.incrementX();
            p.incrementY();
        }
    }
}

class PairManipulator implements Runnable {

    private PairManager pairManager;

    public PairManipulator(PairManager pairManager) {
        this.pairManager = pairManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true)
            pairManager.increment();
    }

}

class PairChecker implements Runnable {

    private PairManager pairManager;

    public PairChecker(PairManager pairManager) {
        this.pairManager = pairManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            pairManager.checkCounter.incrementAndGet();
            pairManager.getPair().checkState();
        }
    }
}

public class CriticalSection {

    static void testApproaches(PairManager pman1, PairManager pman2) {
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        PairManipulator
                pm1 = new PairManipulator(pman1),
                pm2 = new PairManipulator(pman2);

        PairChecker
                pcheck1 = new PairChecker(pman1),
                pcheck2 = new PairChecker(pman2);

        exec.execute(pm1);
        exec.execute(pm2);
        exec.execute(pcheck1);
        exec.execute(pcheck2);

        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("InterruptedException");
        }

        System.out.println("pm1: " + pm1 + "\npm2: " + pm2);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PairManager
                pman1 = new PairManager1(),
                pman2 = new PairManager2();

        testApproaches(pman1, pman2);
    }
}
```

An example output:

```
pm1: Pair: Pair{x=364, y=364} counter = 471421
pm2: Pair: Pair{x=365, y=365} counter = 1015604598
```

This example executed without exception.

In above example I understand how does it work but the problem is in example with explicit locks.
Example with explicit lock from book:

```
class ExplicitPairManager1 extends PairManager {
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    // why synchronized ??
    public synchronized void increment() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            p.incrementX();
            p.incrementY();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}

class ExplicitPairManager2 extends PairManager {
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public void increment() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            p.incrementX();
            p.incrementY();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}

public class ExplicitCriticalSection {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PairManager
                pm1 = new ExplicitPairManager1(),
                pm2 = new ExplicitPairManager2();
        CriticalSection.testApproaches(pm1, pm2);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-4" critical.sections.Pair$PairValuesNotEqualException: Values are not equal: Pair{x=2, y=1}
    at critical.sections.Pair.checkState(CriticalSection.java:49)
    at critical.sections.PairChecker.run(CriticalSection.java:133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
pm1: Pair: Pair{x=1024, y=1024} counter = 3
pm2: Pair: Pair{x=1025, y=1025} counter = 1499445
```

First what I don't understand why author use `synchronized` in ExplicitPairManager1#increment if he use also Lock object? Is that the mistake in the book?

Second problem is that I don't understand why I got exception?

Excpetion was thrown in:

```
class PairChecker implements Runnable {

    private PairManager pairManager;

    public PairChecker(PairManager pairManager) {
        this.pairManager = pairManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            pairManager.checkCounter.incrementAndGet();
            pairManager.getPair().checkState();  // here was thrown an exception
        }
    }
}
```

Why I got excpetions and author dont? Is that possible JVM behavior is different on different systems? I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Java 8.

Comment: What's the purpose of `storage` variable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to synchronize on the same object if you want to establish a critical section for multiple threads.

Your exception is getting thrown for pair modified in `ExplicitPairManager2`.

Let's see how possible exception-causing flow looks like:

1. `ExplicitPairManager2.lock.lock()` gets acquired
2. `ExplicitPairManager2.p.incrementX()` happens
3. PairChecker calls `getPair()`
4. PairChecker acquires pairManager's internal (`this`) monitor, but it is different than `ExplicitPairManager2.lock`
5. the result of `getPair()` therefore has x != y

so in the end there is no critical section.

In other words, while modifying, you were using two different objects to synchronize:

- `ExplicitPairManager2.lock` to write
- internal monitor of `ExplicitPairManager2` (`this`) to create a copy for checking state